# Sidr is appending #sidr-0 in URL in first time and nothing happens

Tags: drupal, sidr

I am using Sidr in my Drupal 7 website to create a responsive menu. I am using [Responsive Menus module](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus) with [Sidr library](https://www.berriart.com/sidr/). I have enabled Aggregate JavaScript and CSS files option also in my website. There has been already a menu for big screens such as Desktop etc and I have passed the id of this element (which is #main-menu) to Sidr, as suggested in the documentation. I have not installed [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module. Hence I believe that I am using default jQuery provided by Drupal 7 framework. Running `console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);` returns 1.4.4 in Chrome console in my PC.

The problem is that in the mobile device, whenever I touch menu button, it appends `#sidr-0` in URL as `www.example.com/#sidr-0`  and nothing happens at first attempt. However, it starts working smoothly from second time onwards. Also from second time onwards, nothing has been appended to the URL and it remains same i.e. `www.example.com`

This happens on all devices (I have checked already on Android and iPhone). It seems that it is loading sidr library at first attempt and once it is download to the device, it starts working fine.

Is there any workaround for this issue? I certainly don't like any user to touch menu icon twice. It gives a negative impression as well.

Comment: For complex menus , i think it's better to make own custom responsive , you'll win in size loaded and code lines and finally handle like you want your  menu

Comment: @Fky : I agree with you. However my menu is very simple. It just contains 4 items such as "Home", "About Me", "My work" and "Contact Me". Can you please explain more about your suggestion?

Comment: Your menu is small , so custom development to handle it will be small , it's a bad thing to use framework for little things. So you can build own block / menu and apply theming like you in few lines